# Android wear Vibrate like the call

Tags: android, wear-os

I am building a location based alarm system. I want the wear to vibrate until the user wakes up and stops it. This is similar to the call dialog of the Android wear. How do I achieve this?

I could just vibrate for fixed time using the following code.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{200, 200, 200, 200, 200})
                .setContentTitle("Wake Up")
                .setContentText("Train reached "+stationName)

                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .addAction(someAction);
```